# How stop rpcbind from being started on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

My Arch Linux's systemd starts `rpcbind` automatically. What do I have to do to stop `systemd` to do this? There are no remote filesystems in `/etc/fstab`. The only thing I found why rpcbind gets started is that is supposedly wanted by multi-user target but there is no service in the directory. How can I figure out why it is really started?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an [open bug report on the Arch tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/41433).

Your best be would be to mask the service:

```
systemctl mask rpcbind.service
```

See Lennart Poettering's series of blog posts, [systemd for Administrators, Part V](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/three-levels-of-off) for details on masking:

> 3. You can mask a service. This is like disabling a service, but on steroids. It not only makes sure that service is not started automatically anymore, but even ensures that a service cannot even be started manually anymore. This is a bit of a hidden feature in systemd, since it is not commonly useful and might be confusing the user. But here's how you do it:
>
> ```
> $ ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/ntpd.service
> $ systemctl daemon-reload
> ```
>
> By symlinking a service file to `/dev/null` you tell systemd to never start the service in question and completely block its execution. Unit files stored in `/etc/systemd/system` override those from `/lib/systemd/system` that carry the same name. The former directory is administrator territory, the latter terroritory of your package manager. By installing your symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/ntpd.service` you hence make sure that systemd will never read the upstream shipped service file `/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service`.
>
> systemd will recognize units symlinked to `/dev/null` and show them as masked. If you try to start such a service manually (via systemctl start for example) this will fail with an error.

Comment: Thank you that is an option but I'd like to know why it is started in the first place. I didn't enable it and none of the nfs services are running by default.

Comment: My bad, sorry, didn't read the bug report. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

If there's no `wanted/rpcbind.service` present it's most likely not being started directly but being started via socket activation. You can tell if that's how it was most recently started by looking for `indirect` instead of `static` in the `Loaded` line of the status output (note that `systemctl` automatically added the `.service` to the unit name as it wasn't included on the command line):

```
$ systemctl status rpcbind
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-03-31 15:39:29 WIB; 37min ago
 Main PID: 6763 (rpcbind)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
           └─6763 /sbin/rpcbind -w
```

Regardless, you can check to see if you have socket activation enabled:

```
$ systemctl status rpcbind.socket
● rpcbind.socket - RPCbind Server Activation Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Fri 2017-03-31 15:39:29 WIB; 37min ago
   Listen: /var/run/rpcbind.sock (Stream)
           [::]:111 (Stream)
           0.0.0.0:111 (Stream)
```

(In the example above I'd disabled the unit but not yet stopped the existing listener that starts `rpcbind` when it receives a request.)

Executing the following should kill both and make sure they never start:

```
$ systemctl disable rpcbind.service rpcbind.socket
$ systemctl stop rpcbind.service rpcbind.socket
```

A status check should then produce something along the lines of:

```
$ systemctl status rpcbind.service rpcbind.socket
● rpcbind.service - RPC bind service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2017-03-31 16:17:05 WIB; 49s ago
 Main PID: 6763 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

[...log messages...]
Mar 31 16:17:05 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped RPC bind service.

● rpcbind.socket - RPCbind Server Activation Socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2017-03-31 16:17:48 WIB; 6s ago
   Listen: /var/run/rpcbind.sock (Stream)
           [::]:111 (Stream)
           0.0.0.0:111 (Stream)

[...log messages...]
Mar 31 16:17:48 myhost systemd[1]: Closed RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
Mar 31 16:17:48 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
```

Answer (score 0):

With systemd the way to stop services starting at boot is to use the `disable` option, so in this instance you would use the command `systemctl disable rpcbind`, below is an example of the output I see when running on my Fedora 20 system;

```
chris::test::07:08:29-> sudo systemctl disable rpcbind
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rpcbind.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/rpcbind.socket'
```

Comment: Thx, but the service is disabled. There is not even a directory /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants on my machine and no rpcbind.service in multi-user.target.wants.

Comment: Then I don't think the service is being started by systemd, it may be that another service is starting rpcbind. You could try looking at ```systemctl list-unit-files --type=service``` which will show all services with systemctl.

Comment: What should I look out for?

Comment: Are you actually using NFS? If not then all of the following services may be affecting it/starting rpcbind; ```nfs-config```, ```rpc-statd``` & ```nfs-server```.

Comment: In fact I've just seen @jasonwryan's response, that looks like a better option :).

Comment: None of nfs-config, rpc-statd, nfs-server are running.